# When using generator-meanjs, why does naming a module "copywars" give me the error "Unknown provider: $stateProvider"?

Tags: npm, meanjs

I'm brand new to MEAN so I thought I'd use the yeoman generators to make a game called CopyWars.

Here are the steps to recreate:

Install and run mongodb and install npm

```
sudo npm install -g generator-meanjs
mkdir copywars-meanjs
cd copywars-meanjs
yo meanjs
yo meanjs:angular-module copywars
grunt test
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module copywars due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module core due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3705
        at getService (/home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3832)
        at invoke (/home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3859)
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3788
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=core&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24stateProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3705%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3832)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3859)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3788
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3810
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=copywars&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20core%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24stateProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3705%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3832)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3859)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3788%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dcore%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Aunpr%255D%2520Unknown%2520provider%253A%2520%2524stateProvider%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Funpr%253Fp0%253D%252524stateProvider%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3705%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520getService%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3832)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520invoke%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3859)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3788%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3810
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3810
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module copywars due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module core due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3705
        at getService (/home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3832)
        at invoke (/home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3859)
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3788
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=core&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24stateProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3705%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3832)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3859)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3788
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3810
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=copywars&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20core%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20%24stateProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3705%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3832)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3859)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3788%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dcore%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Aunpr%255D%2520Unknown%2520provider%253A%2520%2524stateProvider%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.16%252F%2524injector%252Funpr%253Fp0%253D%252524stateProvider%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3705%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520getService%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3832)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520invoke%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3859)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9876%252Fbase%252Fpublic%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.js%253F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%253A3788%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fpublic%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F7dcf1b25480258d399759429338cedc57239f2d1%3A3810
        at /home/intrepion/Code/MEAN/copywars-meanjs/public/lib/angular/angular.js:3810
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out my problem.

When you run "yo meanjs" the first question it asks is "What would you like to call your application?"

Whatever answer you give, creating a module of the same name will cause issues.

Since I called the application "copywars" I was getting errors whenever I made a module called "copywar" or "copywars"
I am able to get around this by changing my application name or changing the module name.